# SpecFlow Test cannot be run with Playwright.NET

Tags: c#, specflow, playwright, playwright-sharp

I created a `specflow` project using c# and `playwright`. No issues with the code, but the tests do not run When using test explorer on visual studio.
when i run the test, the results always say:

> test not run

I installed the  nuget packages for `playwright` and `specflow` and cannot see any errors. Are there any other components required for the test to run?
I m using `playwright.net` with c#
any advise would be appreciated
sample feature file:

```
Feature: feature example

@mytag
Scenario: Open test
    Given the test page is open
    When I navigate to the links page
    Then I will see all the links
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

**1- Are the tests ignored?**

If you have r# Open one of the test files and check if there is a little gray eye-like icon to the left of test method declarations, if so, tests are ignored.

if not on r#, open vs text explorer and check if your tests are there, and if they are, there is something on the window that says they are ignored.

This weirdly happens when your file path is too long (i.e deep in the folder hierarchy, or maybe not so eep, but long folder and file names.

try to move you test project up in the folder hierarchy on the drive.

**2- Do you have a test runner for the test framework?** i.e nunit test runner?
If you don't see your tests on the test explorer at all, try installing test framework's runner as a vs extension.

Comment: Yes the test is visible on the test explorer but it just doesn't run. i installed the nunit test runner as vs extension but still doesn't work. in the past I used selenium with c# and it was ok. i m using playwright.net with c#. wondering if there is something else  require enabling for the test to run

Comment: Regarding the status of the tests, it just says 'Not Run' so they are not ignored

Comment: Have you checked the total path length for your tests / tried to move them up in the directory structure? as weird as it may sound, I had this problem solved by doing that less than a week ago

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to move the solution upper in the directory hierarchy?

ie.
c:\projects\mycompany.projects.crmprojects.solution1\project1\testproject....\test.cs

becomes

c:\projects\solution1\project1\test.cs

Comment: Hi yes I did. i figured out the issue was with the account signing to spec flow. now the test an be run but they always pass. I  noticed this error in the log but the test just pass:  Missing [assembly:RuntimePlugin] attribute in EndTests, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null

Comment: this is a sample of the Given section of the test. It just passes all the time even if i put the wrong url and doesnt launch the page.
    [Binding]
    public class OpenTestSteps
    {
        [Given(@"the page is open")]
        public  async void GivenThePageIsOpen()
        {
            using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
            await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync(headless: false);

          
            var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
            await page.GoToAsync("http://www.testdummy.com");